# Intellisense not working in Power Query for Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, microsoft365

In Power Query **for Excel**, Intellisense does not work for me in any of the places where it should (Advanced Editor, Formula Bar, Add custom column dialog).

It was properly selected in Query Options:

[image]

This is a new computer with fresh installs of Windows 11 Professional 64 bit and Microsoft Office 365 64 bit.

I have Microsoft 365 Excel Version 2211 (Build 15831.20190 Click-to-Run) Current Channel (64 bit) running on Windows 11.

I have done an "online repair" of my Microsoft 365 installation.

I have no idea if this is relevant, but intellisense does work as expected in the PQ Editor in Power BI Desktop, just not in the PQ Editor in Excel.

***edit:** It seems this is workbook specific, as it does not occur in other workbooks than the one with the problem. But what could be causing it?*

Comment: It seems this is workbook specific, as it does not occur in other workbooks than the one with the problem. But what could be causing it?